# How to create an Appcelerator Alloy android application with multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, titanium, titanium-alloy

In android, it is common for an app to have multiple activities to represent different entry points/views.  The most basic case is a ToDo app, where the main activity launches the app to the index view, but a secondary activity launches into a specific ToDo view. While this works perfectly for Titanium classic apps, an Alloy app is horribly broken if the secondary activity is launched BEFORE the main app is launched.

Here is an simple example: https://github.com/DaKaZ/multiactive

You can initiate the second activity by using ADB:

```
adb shell am start -n "com.kaztopia.multiactive/.SecondActivityActivity" -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -e "message" "HERE_I_AM"
```

As I said in the readme, if the app is already running, the second activity works perfectly.  But if it is not, it is horribly broken.  As you can see in the SecondActivity.js file I have tried to find a way to bootstrap alloy, but this does not work:

```
if (typeof Alloy === 'undefined' || typeof Backbone === 'undefined' || typeof Alloy.Globals === 'undefined') {
  Ti.API.debug("-------------------------  NO ALLOY -------------------------");
  if (typeof Alloy === 'undefined') {
      var Alloy = require('alloy');
  }
  if (typeof Backbone === 'undefined') {
      var Backbone = require('alloy/backbone');
  }
  if (typeof _ === 'undefined') {
      var _ = require('alloy/underscore')._;
  }
  try {
    Ti.API.debug('Calling app.run()');
    require('app').run();
  } catch (err) {
    Ti.API.debug('Calling app._restart()');
    Ti.App._restart();
  }
  setTimeout(openModal, 1000);
}
```

Comment: This appears to be related to a bug in titanium, I have opened a Jira ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-4813